# DataTables - force cell content regeneration (via custom display renderer)

Tags: caching, datatables

One of my column holds timestamps in the past, and I'm using momentjs in my custom `render` function to convert it to relative duration form like `1 hour 3 minutes 45 seconds`, which makes the presentation of the data in this column **always volatile**, and need to be regenerated to be *current*.

However, it looks my custom render (esp. of type `display`) is only called once to created the table-cell, then the cell content is cached.

I wonder if there's a way to force the cell regeneration or force invalidate the display cache?

The closest thing IMHO is to use the `order` event, but not sure how.

Though, I doubt using the `order` event is the best way to go, is there any better way?

BTW. I'm using DataTables `1.10.0`.

Comment: I would very much like to have an answer on this question aswell.